# Selenium to record browser actions as video

Tags: firefox, selenium, video, screen

I wrote a selenium code to run automation in webpage via Firefox
I need to record the browser actions like a visual
Is there any way to record the screen on firefox as a video using addons or any other. I am using firefox version 34

Comment: Share code with question which you have written. Also which add on you are using?

Comment: Currently, I am not using add on ? I just take screenshots

Answer (score 5):

You can include it in your test. Here is an example for C#. To make this work, you need to install Microsoft Expression Encoder and add the reference to your project

```cs
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture;

    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
    ScreenCaptureJob vidrec = new ScreenCaptureJob();
    vidrec.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = @"C:/yourPathToSaveFile/yourFilename " + timestamp + ".wmv";
    vidrec.Start();

// your test

vidrec.Stop();
```

Comment: I have two more issues.I am currently running the tests (Other system) via hub and 5 browsers opening parallel, I want to record video of each browser

Answer (score -1):

http://learnseleniumtesting.com/recording-selenium-test-execution/

```
using System;
.
.
using OpenQA.Selenium;
.
.
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Profiles;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder;

namespace FRAMEWORK
{
    //Call this method in setup method.   
    public static void StartRecordingVideo()
    {
        //Provide setting in config file if you want to do recording or not.
        if (testEInfo.isRecording)
        {
            job = new ScreenCaptureJob();
            job.CaptureRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            job.ShowFlashingBoundary = true;
            //provide the location where you want to save the recording.
            job.OutputPath = AutomationLogging.newLocationInResultFolder;
            job.Start();
        }
    }
}
```